# How to display MDN reference in JavaScript file

Tags: javascript, visual-studio-code, javascript-intellisense

**I have a strange problem in my vocode**

- My editor has disabled the refences and the definition that is shown from MDN not in HTML nor CSS  but it is only in my JavaScript file

I have made many things like :
**write two following lines in settings.JSON and no thing happens**

"editor.hover.enabled": true,
"editor.hover.delay": 300,

**I has installed `intellisense` and the same result no thing changed**

> I need to show it when hovering

Comment: Only MDN links or all site links are disabled?
And could u paste related codes.

Comment: No, it disabled in all javaScript files

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See this [ref](https://code.visualstudio.com/updates/v1_38#_mdn-reference-for-html-and-css).

There is **no** official support for  **MDN reference for javascript** until now.

[This extension](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=samundrak.esdoc-mdn) may help to some extent.

Comment: But sometimes I see a box that show when hover on function object , var and for and it displays definition for how to use the code